# Type variable to generic type

Tags: c#

Sorry my bad english.
My code in C#.

I have variable:

```
Type t = /* Variable with any unknown type */
```

And i need in used template:

```
var b = GetData</* I need used variable t in here */>();
```

How do it?

---

### OR

I need variable

```
object c = /*any data*/
Type type = /*any type*/
```

I need this:

```
var b = (type)c;
```

How do it?

Comment: You can use reflection, but in most situations if you're doing that then there isn't much use to using the generic function to begin with as the entire purpose of generics is to get *compile time* type safety.  If you're losing that through reflection then it's generally best to just avoid generics entirely, if there is a non-generic version of the functionality you want.

Comment: I agree with @Servy, and I'd like to specify the exceptional situations in which using reflection for this purpose is actually reasonable: If there is a lot of generic code within your method (including other classes) that makes sense to be compile time type safe, it may be worth using one call with reflection to "lift" your untyped object into a typesafe code segment.

Comment: Just a note. C++ has templates. C# has generics. While they share some qualities (visual and otherwise), they are different enough that the term for one should not be used for the other.

Comment: In the second example, why would you want to do that cast? If you do not know at compile time what `type` will be, you cannot call any `type`-specific members on `b` anyway, so why cast at all?

Comment: `var b = (type)c;`- **var** doesn't work this way. var should be resolved at *compile* time, but you are using `type` variable that is defined in *runtime* - it won't compile at all.

Comment: Maybe you want to use `dynamic` instead of `var`? What version of .Net do you use?

Comment: @Artemix It will compile, `var` will just resolve to `object`, so it won't really be *useful*.  Even `dynamic` won't help.  It's only useful if you know *at compile time* that the type will have such and such a memeber.  In a situation such as this you generally wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

In this case if `c` could actually be a different type but is convertible then you can use something like this.

For example "123" is a string but convertible to an integer.

```
object c = "123";

Type type = typeof(int);

var b = Convert.ChangeType(c, type);
```

Comment: Note this is only valid for conversions between a small number of types; it doesn't solve the problem in the general case.  It's also actually *converting* a type, not *casting* a type.  There's a *significant* difference between the two.  The question is referring to casting, not converting, as it stands.

Comment: I think the op could be asking about converting - it's not that clear.  But yes you're right - there is a significant difference - I'll update my answer.

Comment: Also note this answer isn't showing how to call a generic method with a `Type` object.

Comment: So?  The body of the question asks for solution1 OR solution2.  I have provided a solution for no. 2 which does not mention generics.

Comment: No, you have *not* provided a solution for the second option.  The result of the second option is a variable of type `object` not a variable of type `type`.  He is thinking that he could then pass `b` to the generic method and have it infer the appropriate generic argument.  It would not using your code.  This is because he's not interested in converting the underlying object; he's interested in a dynamic cast, but a dynamic cast is fundamentally impossible.

Comment: Maybe - but that's a lot of assumptions for what the op is thinking.

Comment: And what is your justification for thinking that he wants to convert the value?  If How would that be related to the initial problem of dynamically invoking a generic method?

Comment: Ultimately - it's unclear.  The op said c could hold "any data" - so it could hold "123".  Maybe he just needs a way to change this into the needed type - and avoid generics all together.  This is what I provided an answer for - maybe it will help him - maybe not.

Comment: Maybe - but that's a lot of assumptions for what the op is thinking.

Comment: Better to provide an answer that might be helpful based on assumptions, than to criticise a possibly helpful answer based on assumptions.

Comment: Well, first off, I'm quite confident that my assumptions are more likely than yours, but in any case, what's your basis for that statement?  Why do I have a higher burden of proof than you do?  You're the one asserting that this is a solution.  I'd think that the burden of proof lies more strongly on you to assert that this is appropriate.  If you are unsure of what the OP is actually asking for you shouldn't guess in an answer, you should wait for the OP to further clarify the question.

Comment: I didn't say that you have a higher burden of proof than me.  My assumptions have led to me providing some working code that some people may find useful.  What have your assumptions done?  Given me a -1.  Good job.

Comment: You've provided code that is highly unlikely to help the OP in any way, and if he spends time continuing down the avenue of approach that you've shown he will only be wasting his time.  I described in my first comment an avenue of approach he could take to solve the problem, but more importantly I indicated that this is unlikely to be a solution to his underlying problem and that he should take a step back and reevaluate his approach.  Without knowing anything about what that actual underlying problem is, I cannot assist him further in that regard.